# hershey font file format; meaning of of first coordinate

Tags: fonts, reverse-engineering, file-format

I am trying to understand the JHF file format that the public domain *Hershey* vector fonts are distributed in.

What I know so far:

- They are ASCII files with one glyph per line.
- The first 5 line characters are some kind of id field.
- Three characters follow: a decimal integer N, right-aligned to three positions using spaces.
- (2*N) characters follow; they are either "raise pen" indicators (" R", so a space followed by a capital R), or 2 ASCII characters indicating an (x, y) pair of one signed integer each, the value of which can be determined by subtracting 82 (ASCII code of R) from the ASCII value.

My problem is that I don't understand the very first (x, y) pair. If I parse and render the font, everything seems fine if I just omit that first pair. But their meaning is unclear. It is not some character ID (because the same (x, y) values are often shared by different characters; and by experimenting with the values I found I have not found any correlation to the encoded glyphs (e.g. size information, or some offset information).

Looking around the web, people often seem to quote this page:

http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/hershey/

This page describes the font format, but it is vague. It claims that the first (x, y) pair is a "position", but it doesn't explain what position.

I hope someone happens to know...

Answer (score 0):

Right I figured it out.

Those first two numbers are not an (x,y) point, they both determine the width of the letter relative to the origin; first number is width to the left side; second number is width to the right side. So, used for kerning.

Just leaving that here in case anyone will wonder the same thing in the future...